# How to retrieve specific connectionstring from a performancecounter

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, connection-pooling, performancecounter

I have some problems with the Connection Pool and I know that using a PerformanceCounter I can get several information about it, here the documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503(v=vs.100).aspx

But since a pool is create for every different connectionstring I use, I do not understand how to use for example **NumberOfPooledConnections** that returns a generic number of pooled connection.

So, how should I use it? Can I retrieve the specific connectionstring of the performancecounter??

Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance counter is just a counter - `NumberOfPooledConnections` is just number, it is not list or array of connections.

Comment: And what does it count? All the pooled connections in all the pools? How is it usefull?

Comment: @Mackho, yes, it is useful for monitoring, one example is here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f7f6581a-4906-4708-aab6-966eb1f5f56a

Comment: Since in my application (IIS) I use different connectionstrings (personalized for user), I don't understand what does the counter count? The sum of all pooled connections for all the different connectionstrings?

Comment: @Mackho yes. I personally don't see much use in this counter.

Comment: Thank you, and what could be a better way to monitor different connectionpools in my scenario?

Comment: @Mackho depends on what exactly you want to monitor. And how.

Comment: I told you, I would want to monitor how many connections are pooled in each connectionpool!